# jboss as7 tld not found

Tags: jboss, module, struts-1, tld

I am working on porting a legacy web app to JBOSS AS7.  The code works fine in Tomcat 6 or JBOSS 5.  The app uses struts-1.2.9 and we also have some custom taglib defined which are giving me problems.

I have a mainScripts.jsp file that defines a taglib

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/lib/abtaglib.tld" prefix="abtag" %>
```

The /WEB-INF/web.xml files includes the following.  Not sure if this is needed!?

```
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>abtags</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/abtaglib.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

When I access this page in JBOSS AS7, I get the following error. It seems that the jboss web modules cannot access the files in my war file.  How can I fix this?

```
10:04:53,881 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) insert page='/WEB-INF/jsps/mainScripts.jsp'.
10:04:53,991 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/web].[jsp]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004036: File "/WEB-INF/lib/abtaglib.tld" not found
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:53) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:147) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:147) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:385) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:446) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1372) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:132) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:256) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:194) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:359) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:326) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:606) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:308) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:718) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:655) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:940) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:607) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:99) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:135) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:760) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:892) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.common.mainLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f0(mainLayout_jsp.java:482)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.common.mainLayout_jsp._jspService(mainLayout_jsp.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:620) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:553) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:482) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:302) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at com.sprint.struts.action.StrutsServlet.process(StrutsServlet.java:67) [classes:]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
```

Comment: Is there a file `"/WEB-INF/lib/abtaglib.tld"`? If not, you should be using whatever the TLD the TLD *actually* defines.

Comment: Yes, the "/WEB-INF/lib/abtaglib.tld" is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.  It seems that Jasper, which is in a JBOSS module (jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar), is unable to access my tld file located in /WEB-INF/lib/.  The same code works in JBOSS 5, Websphere 6 and in any version of Tomcat.  I think this is a class loading issue.  When I moved my tld file inside a /META-INF folder within a jar file it started working.  I did not need the taglib reference in the web.xml anymore, because the tld file is automatically picked up from the jar file /META-INF folder.  Here's the final code:

Declare taglib in jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://mycompany/abtags" prefix="abtag" %>
```

packaged tld file insde a jar:

```
/WEB-INF/lib/XYZ.jar
```

XYZ.jar content:

```
/META-INF/abtaglib.tld
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

abtaglib.tld content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib
  PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">
<taglib>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>1.1</jsp-version>
    <short-name>abtag</short-name>
    <uri>http://mycompany/abtags</uri>
    <display-name>XYZ Tag</display-name>
...
```

Comment: Also if you have imports in your jsp like; 

    <%@ taglib prefix="abtag" uri="/META-INF/abtag.tld" %>

change them to 

    <%@ taglib uri="http://mycompany/abtags" prefix="abtag" %>

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem with Jboss 8(Wildfly 8). Copied all taglib "*.tld" files into META_INF folder, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the URI defined in your tld file and, yes, define it's location in your web.xml. For example :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://mycompany/jsp/abtablib" prefix="abtag" %>
```

If you're using a standard taglib, just put the jar in your classpath and use the correct URI.
Here is an example with the core jstl taglib (put jstl-1.2.jar in your classpath) :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: I found the solution.  For some reason the Jasper, which is in a JBOSS module (jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar), is unable to access my tld file in /WEB-INF/lib/.  The same exact code works fine in JBOSS 5, Websphere 6 and in any version of Tomcat.  I think this is a class loading issue.  However, if I package the same tld file inside a jar file it works fine.